# Creating Groups for Xcode Templates

Tags: swift, xml, xcode, templates

Does anyone know if there is an issue with Xcode templates and creating Groups?

I have tried to do it using the following:

```
<key>TestClass.swift</key>
<dict>
    <key>Group</key>
    <array>
        <string>CustomClasses</string>
    </array>
    <key>Path</key>
    <string>TestClass.swift</string>
</dict>
```

A Group folder, with the correct yellow colour, is created.  However, When you try to inspect the Swift files inside the Group by clicking on them in Xcode nothing happens.

Looking at the files in Finder you can see that the Swift files do get created but they are simply stored inside the main folder.  No folder is actually created for the Group.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I guess this is quite obscure Xcode stuff but I've worked out how to fix this if anyone is interested.

If you provide a folder for the Nodes you want to put in a Group like this:

```
<key>Nodes</key>
    <array>
        <string>Engine/Camera.swift</string>
        <string>Engine/Node.swift</string>
        <string>Engine/Renderer.swift</string>
        <string>Utility/MathLibrary.swift</string>
        <string>Shaders/Shaders.metal</string>
```

Then you can go ahead and place them in a Group using the method described in the original post:

```
<key>Definitions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Utility/MathLibrary.swift</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Group</key>
            <array>
                <string>Utility</string>
            </array>
            <key>Path</key>
            <string>MathLibrary.swift</string>
        </dict>
```

This is NOT what is described in any of the articles/tutorials I have looked at, for example:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/158/how-to-create-a-custom-xcode-template-for-coordinators

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-create-custom-project-templates-in-xcode-7

These both say to arrange your nodes like this:

```
<key>Nodes</key>
    <array>
        <string>Camera.swift</string>
```

Which will not work if you want to use Groups.